# Error Memory VM java, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, performance, jvm

Friends I need your help, I have to handle a very large file with information (about the file weighs 30 Mb). When processing this information file, java gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:535)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:322)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:94)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:127)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.Printer.printText(Printer.java:170)
    .....
```

My code is:

```
...

    public Document generateXML(File file, String type) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document document = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = document.createElement("data");
            document.appendChild(rootElement);

            Element informacionElement = document.createElement("information");
            rootElement.appendChild(informacionElement);

            Element entityElement = document.createElement("entity");
            entityElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("ANYTHING"));
            informacionElement.appendChild(entityElement);

            Element entityCode = document.createElement("code");
            entityCode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(0000));
            informacionElement.appendChild(entityCode);

            Element fileElement = document.createElement("FILENAME");
            fileElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(file.getName()));
            informacionElement.appendChild(fileElement);

            Element detailElement = document.createElement("detail");
            rootElement.appendChild(detailElement);

            Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
            Scanner tmpFile = new Scanner(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

            String[] tmpTags = keyXml.get(type);
            int row = 1;

            while (tmpFile.hasNextLine()) {

                Element rowElement = document.createElement("row");
                filaElement.setAttribute("id", Integer.toString(row));

                Scanner tmpLine = new Scanner(tmpFile.nextLine());
                tmpLine.useDelimiter("\\|");
                int index = 0;
                while (tmpLine.hasNext()) {
                    Element element = document.createElement(tmpTags[index]);
                    String text = tmpLine.next().trim();
                    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
                    filaElement.appendChild(element);
                    ++index;
                }
                detailElement.appendChild(filaElement);
                ++fila;
            }
            return document;
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HandlerXML.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
...
```

This code generates the following XML document:

```
    <data>
        <information>
            <entity>ANYTHING</entity>
            <code>0000</code>
            <filename>filename_XXX</filename>
        </information>
        <detail>
            <row id="1">
                <tag1>0099</tag1>
                <tag2>2014</tag2>
                <tag3>05</tag3>
                <tag4>0015</tag4>
                <tag5>06</tag5>
                <tag6>06</tag6>
                <tag7>000000000099907</tag7>
                <tag8>098026</tag8>
                <tag9>00000781.40</tag9>
                <tag10>E</tag10>
                <tag11>000000006804750</tag11>
                <tag12>xxx</tag12>
                <tag13>xxxx</tag13>
                <tag14>xxx</tag14>
                <tag15></tag15>
                <tag16></tag16>
                <tag17>xx</tag17>
                <tag18>xxx</tag18>
                <tag19>1014</tag19>
                <tag20>05</tag20>
                <tag21>11111</tag21>
                <tag22>1014</tag22>
                <tag23>00000000000000000000</tag23>
                <tag24>3</tag24>
                <tag25>20101</tag25>
                <tag26>00000000</tag26>
                <tag27>46671</tag27>
                <tag28>1</tag28>
                <tag29>N</tag29>
                <tag30></tag30>
                <tag31></tag31>
                <tag32>A</tag32>
                <tag33></tag33>
                <tag34></tag34>
                <tag35></tag35>
                <tag36></tag36>
                <tag37></tag37>
                <tag38></tag38>
            </row>
            ............   
        </detail>
    </data>
```

word where xml data obtained is:

**0099|2014|05|0015|06|06|00000000003101|066671|000077777.00|E|000000002719415|xxx|xxxxxx                   |xxxxxxxx                |      |                         |xxxxxx                   |                         |1014|05|12254758|1014|00000000000000000000|3|20101|00000000|748596|1|X|               |   |Q|  | |         |         |   **

Now imagine that the xml must be generated for 100000 lines of information, and if you are wondering, all the lines must be converted to XML format.

The problem is, when you convert the object into a **STRING** to **DOCUMENT** I get the error that I showed earlier, the function I use to transform **DOCUMENT** to **STRING** is:

```
    private static String convertDocumentToString(Document doc) {
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer;
        try {
            transformer = tf.newTransformer();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
            return writer.getBuffer().toString();
        } 
        catch (TransformerException e) {}
        return "";
    }
```

Now this error is virtual memory and java VM workaround is to increase the memory with **-Xmx####m**, but I wonder if this is solved by another way, try to handle the data type with: String, StringBuilder and byte. Could anyone solve this question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your piece of code?

Comment: Please tell us what kind of operations you're doing on these big files, there could be ways of do the same operations while "streaming" data instead of having it in ram.

Comment: Without knowing anything about what you're doing it's impossible to help.

Comment: sorry, if I did not express well, and not give much information

Comment: 30 MB is very large file? Used to, as I was a child, now it's a joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"30 MB" isn't really that large.

SUGGESTION: add this to your Java command line: `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

ALSO:

- Definitely familiarize yourself with the Java profiler, [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html).  It ships with the JDK.
- Here is a good article for troubleshooting this kind of problem: [Anatomy of a PermGen Memory Leak](http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/permgen-memory-leak/)

'Hope that helps!

Comment: There is no PermGen since Java 7 anymore.

Comment: [Java7 still has PermGen](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.de/2011/10/java-7-features-permgen-removal.html); and it can still be depleted.  The main point is to encourage the OP to determine exactly what's causing the problem.  Two strong suggestions: 1) Learn to use [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) (or equivalent), 2) Read up on [Memory Troubleshooting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/memleaks.html)

Answer (score 1):

"a very large file" does not indicate that your program will use a very large amount of memory. It more likely means that you may spend quite a bit of time to process the file, but really not much to do with the space you use.

Only the currently relevant portion of the file should stay in memory.

Answer (score 1):

> but quies know if this is solved by another way

Yes, there certainly is another way: when serializing your XML, do not use `StringWriter` as the destination. If you want your XML to end up in a file, then create an appropriate `FileWriter` for it, and hand that one over to your XML serializing code.

Had you included more from your exception's stacktrace, I would possibly have been able to give you more precise advice than above. Your actual code which produces the exception would also have helped.